# why PreferredSizeWidget still not work after wrapped with PreferredSize in flutter

Tags: flutter

After I wrapped the appBar sub component with `PreferredSize` in flutter, the appBar still did not work and shows:

```
The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'.
```

this is my code which build the appBar and body of flutter page:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(context),
      body:_buildBody(context),
    ));
  }
```

and this is the `_buildAppBar` implemention:

```
Widget _buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return PreferredSize(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, top: 0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ToolbarItemAlwaysOnTop(),
            Expanded(child: Container()),
            // ToolbarItemSponsor(),
            ToolbarItemSettings(
              onSettingsPageDismiss: () {
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(34),
    );
  }
```

what should I do to make it work? I have readed the question and suggest to extend the `PreferredSizeWidget`,  I could not implement `PreferredSizeWidget` in my code right now(I have tried but not work for this situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace return type of `_buildAppBar()` from `Widget` to `PreferredSize`

you can check From `PreferredSize` class

> `class PreferredSize extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget`

Answer (score 1):

Just make the return type of _buildAppBar(context) function  return preferredSize